# tester program for my subclass java

Tags: java, class

Output: Write algorithms and programs to create a BetterRectangle sub-class - refer to E9.10 on page 459 in the text. Provide a BetterRectangle sub-class that extends the Rectangle class of the standard Java library by adding methods to compute the area and perimeter of the rectangle, as well as a valid constructor for the sub-class. Provide a tester program that will execute and validate the new methods of the extended class. All output should be handled by the tester class, not the super or sub-class.

Input: As required to execute the tester class. All input should be handled by the tester class, not the super or sub-class.

Requirements: Use only material covered in the first nine chapters. Style requirements as discussed in class expected. Class design guidelines as discussed in class and described in chapter 8 expected. Import libraries as required.

You must write at least two programs: one would be the sub-class extension of the java.awt.Rectangle class; and one tester class that will perform the actions required to execute and validate all the added or overridden methods of the extended sub-class. Do not add any instance variables to the sub-class. In the sub-class constructor, use the setLocation() and setSize() methods of the Rectangle class. Include an override for the toString() and equals() methods, if appropriate.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class BetterRectangle extends Rectangle

{

public BetterRectangle(int i, int j, int Width, int height

{

super.setLocation(i, j);
super.setSize(width, height);

}
public double calculatePerimeter() {
return super.getHeight() * 2 + super.getWidth() * 2;
}

public double calculateArea()  {
return super.getHeight() * super.getWidth();   }}

this is what i have so far but im confused about tester classes, im supposed       to write 2 programs? i have the sub class extention of the java awt.rectangle but im unsure how to do a tester class that performs the actions required to execute and validate all the added or overridden methods of the extended sub-class.
```

please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Answer (score 0):

A Tester Class is really just there to let you test your code. The most straightforward way is to define another class, where in the main method, you run a few cases to make sure your newly-added methods are correct. For example:

```
public class BetterRectangleTester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BetterRectangle r1 = new BetterRectangle(0, 0, 1, 2);
        if (r1.calculatePerimeter != 6){
            System.out.println("calculatePerimeter is wrong!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("calculatePerimeter is working fine.");
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a pretty shoddy Tester Class, and ideally you should be using a unit-testing framework such as JUnit. Generally, it's important to test for "edge cases", as well as all the functions (I didn't do one for calculateArea, for example).